# How do I use the resizable() function of jQuery Ui, to just resize the HEIGHT of the div?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, resizable

That's all I need folks, I have 2 divs(a,b) inside another DIV(c).
So, the C div is resizable, and when I resize it, the A and B divs are also resized by the option alsoResize. Works pretty fine, but now I need to make the height between the two inside divs (a,b) resizable. For now theirs heights are 50%-%50%, so I want to be abble to resize just the Height.

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the constraint options on the inner `div` elements to div C, they should be limited in width by the boundary of C.  From here, you'll also want to set the `minWidth` option to be that same width (of C).

Check out [this page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/#constrain-area) to learn about constraining the inner divs.

In order to set the `minWidth` option on the inner divs, you may need to bind to an event (when the user stops resizing div C) and inside that event, re-set the `minWidth`

Comment: Thats one part.
But what about When I decrease 10% of div A height, It will increase 10% of div B height. So it will keep 100% of the C height. (60%-40%), and so on.

I will take a look on the 'bind' thing, I think this will help me out.